# Сериализация без ссылок

Tags: c#, serialize

Как убрать z:Id="*" и z:Ref="*", для удобного ручного заполнения?

```
<ArrayOfItem xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" z:Id="1" z:Type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[TestBed.ItemPage, TestBed, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]" z:Assembly="0" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestBed">
<_items z:Id="2" z:Size="32">
<Item z:Id="3">
  <Name z:Id="4">Name1</Name>
  <Price>100</Price>
  <Description z:Id="5">Description1</Description>
</Item>
<Item z:Id="6">
  <Name z:Id="7">Name2</Name>
  <Price>300</Price>
  <Socket z:Id="8">Description2</Socket>
</Item>
<Item z:Id="9">
  <Name z:Id="10">Name3</Name>
  <Price>8</Price>
  <Description z:Id="11">Description3</Description>
</Item>
<Item z:Id="12">
  <Name z:Id="13">Name3</Name>
  <Price>18</Price>
  <Description z:Ref="11" i:nil="true" />
</Item>
```

Сериализация:

```
var ser = new NetDataContractSerializer();
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
using (var w = XmlWriter.Create("ser1.xml", settings))
{
  ser.WriteObject(w, Itempages/*коллекция польз. типа*/);
}
```

Comment: Это называется пространства имен. Смотрите, например, здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/q/258960/6766879

Comment: не совсем, проблема была в `NetDataContractSerializer`, он осуществляет тесную привязку пользовательских типов(и обращается через них) , решилось сменой сериализатора со слабой привязкой - на  `DataContractSerializer`